# avr-gcc compiles too large optiboot hex to suit

Tags: gcc, arduino, bootloader, avr-gcc

I'd like to modify Arduino Uno's bootloader (optiboot) in order to increase upload commands timeout from 1s to 8s. So i need to recompile bootloaders and upload it.

I was able to replace deprecated '-mshort-calls' to '-mrelax' and i'm able to compile it but it produces too large binary:

```
MBA-Anton:optiboot asmirnov$ make atmega328
../../../../tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -g -Wall -Os -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-split-wide-types -mrelax -fno-move-loop-invariants -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L  -mrelax '-DLED_START_FLASHES=3' '-DBAUD_RATE=115200'   -c -o optiboot.o optiboot.c
../../../../tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -g -Wall -Os -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-split-wide-types -mrelax -fno-move-loop-invariants -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L  -mrelax '-DLED_START_FLASHES=3' '-DBAUD_RATE=115200' -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x7e00 -Wl,--section-start=.version=0x7ffe -Wl,--relax -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -nostdlib -o optiboot_atmega328.elf optiboot.o 
../../../../tools/avr/bin/avr-size optiboot_atmega328.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    530       0       0     530     212 optiboot_atmega328.elf
../../../../tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -j .version --set-section-flags .version=alloc,load -O ihex optiboot_atmega328.elf optiboot_atmega328.hex
../../../../tools/avr/bin/avr-objdump -h -S optiboot_atmega328.elf > optiboot_atmega328.lst
rm optiboot.o optiboot_atmega328.elf
```

avr-gcc version:

```
MBA-Anton:optiboot asmirnov$ ../../../../tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc --version
avr-gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

MBA-Anton:optiboot asmirnov$
```

I've googled more and i found that pretty the [same config](https://code.google.com/p/optiboot/issues/detail?id=101) produces much smaller binary, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using pretty old (2012 year) avr-gcc from [here](https://www.obdev.at/products/crosspack/download.html)

Comment: Did you try compiling with `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`? That should remove unused sections when linking with `--gc-sections`.

Comment: Would be interesting if that helps with the current GCC version.

Comment: Thanks @Rev, that worked for me on avr-gcc-10.2.0. Got optiboot for atmega328p down to exactly 512 bytes. Without those it was 524b on 10.2 and 530b on 9.3